# share python script / environmental variable

Tags: python

I am working on a python script so as you can imagine I have variables, I have data frames ecc ecc. I create these data frames importing files from excel.

At the same time, I am working with another person and this person asked me to send the python script and all the environment to send him the variables (data frames ecc ecc) instead of sending him all the excel file that I used to create the aforementioned df.

I do not understand the way I am supposed to do it. How can I send the entire environment to allow him to see the df that i see in my spyder script without sending the excel file to upload into the script??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

"The environment" refers to all the environment variables you need to run your script. If you don't need any edit to environment variables in order to run your script, you can just ignore that.

You'll need to send him your Python script (file with .py extension) and excel files. You cannot deliver him pandas dataframes, as they are in memory of your script when running.